# 500 Internal Server Error ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I tried making a simple call using JQuery from a web service.
It gives me "500 Internal Server Error".
Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#sayHelloButton").click(function(event) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "dummyWebsevice.asmx/HelloToYou",
                    data: "{'name': '" + $('#name').val() + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                    },
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
            });
        });

        function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
            alert(result.d);
        }

        function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        }  
    </script>
```

and here is my code at the web service side:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class dummyWebservice : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod()]
    public string HelloToYou(string name)
    {
        return "Hello and welcome, " + name;
    }
[WebMethod()]
public string sayHello()
{
    return "Hi!";
}
```

}

I am sorry if my question is redundant, but I can't seem to find my mistake and I am still very new to this.
Thank you in advance.

I am following the example from this page:
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx

Comment: What do you get when you put a breakpoint in the web service method? Do it hit the method as you expect? what's in the incoming parameter?

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code,and it's working fine.It's look like you have rename the service name in Visual studio.
Please check that your are pointing to correct claas

```
    <%@ WebService Language="C#" 
CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebService.cs" Class="dummyWebservice" %>
```

Comment: I re-did the code all over again and now it seems to work. I guess maybe I accidentally changed something.
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should send your data as this:

```
data: {'name': $('#name').val() },
```

Hope this helps. Cheers